# How to load different pages in interval every minute using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I have a javascript code like this :

```
function loadlink() {
    $('#load_here').load('1.php', function () {
        $(this).unwrap().addClass('scale-in');
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function () {
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 60000);
```

As you see this script will load `1.php` in `div#load_here` every 1 minute.

My concern is currently I have more than 1 php files (lets called them `1.php`, `2.php`, `3.php`, `4.php`, `5.php`, etc.) and I want them to load consecutively every 1 minute? I have no idea to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean every 5s load all files or every 5s load one file and go to next file for next interval?

Comment: not all, every 5 seconds 1.php loaded, on next 5seconds 2.php loaded, and another 5 seconds 3.php loaded

after last.php loaded I also want to back to 1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like

```
<script>
  var index = 1;
  function loadlink() {

    $('#load_here').load(index + '.php', function () {
      $(this).unwrap().addClass('scale-in');
    });
  }

  loadlink(); // This will run on page load
  var timer = setInterval(function () {
    index++;
    loadlink() // this will run after every 1 minute
    if(index == 5) {
       clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: Default value of `index` should be `1` because `0.php` doesn't exist as in question mention

Comment: @Mohammad I am incrementing before I call the loadlink function so we should be ok

Comment: No, in first calling out of interval `index` is `0`

Comment: Ahh, I see. Made the change

Comment: thank you very much it is work, I have made very small changes to make it loop, by changing `clearInterval(timer);` to `index =1` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var files=['1.php','2.php','3.php']//etc
  function loadlink(file) {

    $('#load_here').load(file, function () {
      $(this).unwrap().addClass('scale-in');
    });
  }

  loadlink(files[0]); // This will run on page load
  setInterval(function () {
    var nextFile=files.shift();
    loadlink(nextFile) // this will run after every 5 seconds
    files.push(nextFile);
  }, 60000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

calling link after every`5 sec` and in last will call `first php`. also clear **setInterval** after call finished.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = ['php1','php2','php3','php4','php5'], i = 0;    

    function loadlink(link) {
        console.log('calling link : ', link);
        $('#load_here').load(link, function () {
            $(this).unwrap().addClass('scale-in');
        });
    }


    var intervalId = setInterval(callFileLink, 60000);

     function callFileLink() {
        var link = arr[i];
        console.log("Message to alert every 5 seconds"+ link);
        if(link) {
            loadlink(link);
        }else {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          loadlink(arr[0]);
        }
        i++;
     };
});
```